# Angularjs : Selecting one span tag in one div selects another span tag ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have list of posts that gets displayed using ng-repeat. In this I have one question and multiple answers. Answers are displayed in span tag which behaves as option button. Here is the problem, if I select one answer (option button) from one question then similar numbered answer get selected in another question.

**my code for html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" >
        <form id="pollForm" ng-submit="submitPoll()">

          <span class="quest"> <strong>Poll:</strong>{{post.question}}</span><br>

          <div class="post-container">
          <br>
              <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+ img1 +')'}" ng-click="chgImg(1)" 
                    class="Pollchoice--radio">
              </span>
              <span class="Pollchoice--text">{{post.choice1}}</span><br><br>

              <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+ img2 +')'}" ng-click="chgImg(2)" 
                    class="Pollchoice--radio"></span>
              <span class="Pollchoice--text">{{post.choice2}}</span><br><br>

              <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+ img3 +')'}" ng-click="chgImg(3)" 
                    ng-show="post.choice3" class="Pollchoice--radio"></span>
              <span ng-show="post.choice3" class="Pollchoice--text">{{post.choice3}}</span><br><br>

              <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+ img4 +')'}" ng-click="chgImg(4)" 
                    ng-show="post.choice4" class="Pollchoice--radio"></span>
              <span ng-show="post.choice4" class="Pollchoice--text">{{post.choice4}}</span><br><br>

              <hr/>

              <div>
                  <button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Vote</button> 
                  <span style="margin:0 0 0 20px"> 50,000 votes</span> &#0149; <span> 23 hours left</span> 
              </div>

              <br>
          </div>

          <br><br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**javascript:**

```
      $scope.chgImg = function(varParam){
        //alert(varParam);
        if(varParam === 1){
            $scope.img1 = "/images/chk.svg";$scope.img2 = undefined;
            $scope.img3 = undefined;$scope.img4 = undefined;
        }

        if(varParam === 2){
            $scope.img2 = "/images/chk.svg";$scope.img1 = undefined;
            $scope.img3 = undefined;$scope.img4 = undefined;
        }

        if(varParam === 3){
            $scope.img3 = "/images/chk.svg";$scope.img1 = undefined;
            $scope.img2 = undefined;$scope.img4 = undefined;
        }

        if(varParam === 4){
            $scope.img4 = "/images/chk.svg";$scope.img1 = undefined;
            $scope.img2 = undefined;$scope.img3 = undefined;
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure this is all the code for your problem? Because it doesn't really look valid for me, you're missing some bits and pieces.

Comment: I haven't include css besides Everything is there

Comment: Because I'm using your code and it doens't even show the items in `ngRepeat`, can you make a working demo so we could help you?

Comment: there is no relations between your post object and chgImg function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens due to there are many HTML tags that have the same id.
so you need to differentiate between every id.

for example you will add question id & answer id in order to make it unique.

OR

in your JSON data add a new property called ImageURL and set is undefiend
and in your binding

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+{post.ImageURL}+')'}"
```

and in ng-click pass the object

```
ng-click="chkimg(post)"
```

and in chkimg function set the ImageURL with the value

```
post.ImageURL="/images/chk.svg";
```

Comment: Hi @Hady Allam i tried your solution but now all options of one question is getting selected.

Comment: if you will have 4 answers for every question, you will need ImageUrl1, ImageUrl2, ImageUrl3, ImageUrl4

and use chkimg as you implemented before.

 $scope.chgImg = function(post,varParam){
        if(varParam === 1){      //write implementation
        }

        if(varParam === 2){
            //write implementation
        }

        if(varParam === 3){
      //write implementation      
        }

        if(varParam === 4){
      //write implementation
        }
    };

Comment: but if you will need a better solution.
in **posts** object create another array object e.g. **posts.Options**
in this object add all options to this post and add to it ImageURL property and implement ng-click="chkimg(option)"

Comment: Thanks @Hady Allam your solution is working :). Its taking long time to work as i am new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are some problems with the code, you are iterating over posts array but not using post object in the param of chgImg also your ngrepeat would print as many img1, img2 img3 as many time it would iterate and hence when you set it in scope this would be ambiguous for the scope to reflect the change in any one div, solution to this would be through some index to be associated with the img1+postID something like this and then modify the method accordingly as well.
You can index each element using some index and keep incrementing that in ngrepeat, that way would make the elements unique and allow to keep and index.